# Git rebase -i does nothing

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I'm having some trouble with `git rebase -i` not working as I expect from reading various pieces of online documentation and tutorials.

I'm trying to squash my last four commits into one. Imagine a branch `dev` with remote `origin/dev` and commits

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
│                   └ dev
└ origin/dev
```

And I want to end up here:

```
     ┌ dev
A -> F
│
└ origin/dev
```

Where F contains all the changes from B, C, D and E. So, given that I have `dev` checked out, I should be able to run `git rebase -i origin/dev` or `git rebase -i HEAD~4` then squash C, D and E, right?

Here's my problem: running either of those rebase commands doesn't popup a git window to do anything. The console just returns:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/dev.
```

I'm confused, why is the interactive rebase not working? Is there some problem with my Git configuration?

### Update

`git config --global rebase.autoSquash` returns nothing

Comment: Could you please add the output of `git config --global rebase.autoSquash` to your question?

Comment: Ok so my hopes are destroyed :D Damn it, that was the only anchor I had in mind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer: it *was* my git config after all.

After installing Github's Atom yesterday I'd followed instructions at http://blog.atom.io/2014/03/13/git-integration.html, namely:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

What was happening is that everytime I tried to rebase Atom opened then immediately crashed. Git interpreted this as me finishing the rebase and just picked all commits, which had no net effect.

Annoying problem to find, but got there in the end.

Comment: Nice one! Thats kind of ironic though. The built-in editor of github is crashing while working with git....hahah made my day. Actually this means, atom crashes with a return code of 0. you might check this and maybe send this as a bug to github.

Comment: @Richiban - excellent - i'm having the same issue but with nano. how did you fix it in the end?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I'm afraid I can't really help you here; I didn't really *fix* it, I just stopped using atom.